# Sci-fi short story with aliens on another planet trying to telepathically communicate with humans on Earth to prevent a catastrophic bombing

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, telepathy

I am looking for a story about extraterrestials that live on a planet not too far from Earth. I believe they try to communicate with humans via telepathy to prevent a catastrophe, since humans intend to send an atomic (or H-?) bomb to the planet. I think the attempts to communicate with Earth were unsuccessful and they (and/or Earth?) get destroyed in the end.

I read it about 20 years ago, but it might have been from the 50s/60s.

Comment: Arthur C. Clarke's "No Morning After"? As described in [Science fiction short story where aliens contact a drunk about Earth's impending destruction](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217801/science-fiction-short-story-where-aliens-contact-a-drunk-about-earths-impending).

Comment: Though that's not related to at atomic bomb - the Sun is about to go nova.

Comment: I just took a look at "No Morning After". It is very similar, but not the story I was looking for. Thank you though!

Comment: "Earthmen Bearing Gifts" as described here (includes link to full story) https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/262065/28516

Comment: Yes, that's the one. Thank you soooo much.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Alas, not accepted.

Comment: @Valorum Guess I'll write one then :(

Comment: @KathiFromBerlin thanks for letting us know! Since the existing answer was not accepted, I have written one up. If you could mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark beside it, that would be nice. Thanks again!

Answer (score 10):

This is "[Earthmen Bearing Gifts](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64754)" by Fredric Brown.

It was previously answered but not accepted [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/262065/28516).

The entire, very short, story is online [here](https://americanliterature.com/author/fredric-brown/short-story/earthmen-bearing-gifts). These quotes are about a quarter of the text.

> "Yes, Khee. Within an hour the Earth rocket is due to land, and I wish
> to see it. Yes, I know, it will land a thousand miles away, if their
> calculations are correct. Beyond the horizon. But if it lands even
> twice that far the flash of the atomic explosion should be visible.
> And I have waited long for first contact. For even though no Earthman
> will be on that rocket, it will still be first contact--for them. Of
> course our telepath teams have been reading their thoughts for many
> centuries, but--this will be the first physical contact between Mars
> and Earth."

> "Hope it didn't kill anybody. Any Martians, that is. Rog, did it hit
> dead center in Syrtis Major?"
>
> "Near as matters. I'd say it was maybe a thousand miles off, to the
> south. And that's damn close on a fifty-million-mile shot. Willie, do
> you really think there are any Martians?"
>
> Willie thought a second and then said, "No."
>
> He was right.